# web2py URL helper not building good URL's

Tags: url, web2py, view-helpers

I'm starting in web2py and I need to link my static files in my view files.

I'm trying to use URL() helper to make the links but I doesn't work properly...

My application is called red, my controller default and my function index.
My view is called index.html and is inside default folder, when I go to the page I see the view correctly but my URL are all wrong...

So far I tryed:

```
URL('static', 'css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

which gave back: "/static/css/bootstartp.css"

```
URL(a=request.application, args='static/css/bootstrap.css')
```

which gave: "/default/red/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"

```
URL(r=request, arg='static/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

which gave: "/index/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"

```
URL('static/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

which gave: "/default/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"

```
URL(a=request.application, c='static/css/bootstrap.min.css', f='')
```

which gave: "/red/red/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"

I may have tried some more but with no success...

My index function only returns dict().

And my router:

```
routers = dict(

    # base router
    BASE = dict(
        applications = ['red', 'admin'],
        default_application = 'red',
        default_controller = 'default',
        default_function = 'index',
        map_static = True
    )
)
```

I think it's also important to say I'm testing it on google app engine.

I want to get "/red/static/css/bootstrap.min.css".

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you were expecting. The first one is what you should be using, and it looks fine (that is, treat 'static' as the controller and the path within static/ as the function). The last one ('/red/red/...') does look a bit odd, and might be a bug, except that specifying the controller as a path isn't really expected.

Comment: (The first one is missing 'min', but I'd ask you to double-check that.)

Comment: What do you mean missing 'min'? As for the expected I edited the post please review :)

Comment: Ah, 'min', I have both files on the same folder so there's not really a diference.

Comment: as far as i know , static is a special issue. you cant address it like the way you address other controllers and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
URL('static', 'css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

This line is correct, however I needed to turn map_static off in the routers file.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want to link the css files in your view.
You can do this is tow ways.

1.In controller file (inside index():)

```
response.files.append(URL(request.application,'static/css','bootstrap.min.css'))
```

the same command you can use in view (index.html) also:

```
{{response.files.append(URL(request.application,'static/css','bootstrap.min.css'))}}
```

2.in the view (index.html) you can mention the normal css linking.

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{=URL('static/css','bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```

if you want to link this file for the entire application. Then mention the above line in the layout.html page.

Answer (score 0):

To get *"/red/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"*:

```
URL('red/static', 'css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

Comment: I don't want to include the name of the application explicitly... Otherwise I didn't need URL to begin with.